# Make AlarmManager Repeats alarm for a specific number of time - Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I need to set an alarm at perticular time that repeats given number of time only.

There is

```
void set(int type, long triggerAtTime, PendingIntent operation)
```

It gets called for once. I can check preference value and can set it again for my requirement.

I can use this also. At every alarm trigger can check preference value and if limit achieved. Can cancel alarm then.

```
void setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtTime, long interval, PendingIntent operation)
```

I want to avoid this preference stuff within this operation.

Are there other ways of doing this ?

Comment: There isn't any method which directly sets the alarm for a given number of times. Alarm manager provides only three method, look into the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the number of times you want to repeat the alarm as a int value bundled with the intent.

At every trigger decrement the value by 1.

If it reaches 0 cancel it.

No Preferences required.

Comment: Interesting idea, but not sure how reliable it is. If it works for you, accept your own answer. And do post updates if it causes problems.

Comment: @Javanator In my case I am scheduling a service, So, when it get hit in the onStartCommand() method, I can can access the intent that comes in this method parameter, but when I change this value next time when it hit here it is the same as the original value at the time of initiating the AlarmManager, Can you explain where you increment the value and where you did the retrieving and putting back the incremented value back in the intent

Comment: @Diode instead of using setRepeating use set method of AlarmManager. set a fresh alarm everytime for next hit. In the bundle you can pass any fresh value you want

Answer (score 0):

Schedule each next alarm form the previous one and keep track how many times in has executed. Once you reach the number of daily execution times, simply don't schedule the next alarm.

Comment: >keep track ...  is what i asked in the question.

Comment: Right. What is the problem with keeping track yourself? And, no, there are no other ways.

Comment: i am already passing so many values in the preference. Don't want a add on if that can be tricked down by some logic